# Can we have rocky planets the size of gas giants and stars made up of rocky/solid materials?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy

Why are terrestrial planets like the Earth so much smaller in size than the gas giants? Why can't they be the larger ones?
Why are there no stars made up of something solid(/rocky)?
(To generate energy, it could maybe use fission in place of fusion)
But anyways,

**Is it because that would violate some laws of physics or mathematics or is it just the way the universe formed?**
*If it is due to the former then what fundamental laws does it break?*

Comment: The question of why rocky planets are sub-Jovian in mass is very different from the question of why fusion, not fission, happens in stars (the latter happens in e.g. Earth's core). They should be asked separately.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/583331/123208

Comment: As i said in my answer to the linked question, even after >13  billion years of fusion, the universe is still roughly 98% hydrogen and helium (by mass). So it's impossible for a large body to avoid accumulating a lot of hydrogen & helium as it forms.

Comment: Even black holes accumulate them?